# c# nest for elasticsearch: how to convert query that updates particular field of elastic search document to nest?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

We have a document that has a fields "sortScore" and "id". We want to update "sortScore" of particular documents which can be uniquely identified by "id".

I have created elastic search query for v 5.4.1 and this updates the "sortScore" perfectly:

```
POST /stock/1364740/_update
{
    "script" : {
        "inline": "ctx._source.sortScore += params.count",
        "lang": "painless",
        "params" : {
            "count" : 5
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the corresponding c# nest query for this?

Comment: I always go to the GitHub repo and look at their unit tests https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/e78688efbf4f408f0bd769d6a66b8426942dfa6c/src/Tests/Document/Multiple/UpdateByQuery/UpdateByQueryApiTests.cs

Comment: Your query doesn't quite look correct; the uri has an index name, `stock`, and an id, `1364740`, but doesn't appear to have a type name. What is the type name in the `stock` index, and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't quite look correct; the URI has an index name, `"stock"`, and an id, `"1364740"`, but doesn't appear to have a type name.

An Update request would look like the following with NEST

```cs
var updateResponse = client.Update<object>(1364740, u => u
    .Index("stock")
    .Script(s => s
        .Inline("ctx._source.sortScore += params.count")
        .Lang("painless")
        .Params(d => d
            .Add("count", 5)
        )
    )
);
```

which produces the request JSON

```
POST http://localhost:9200/stock/object/1364740/_update 
{
  "script": {
    "params": {
      "count": 5
    },
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source.sortScore += params.count"
  }
}
```

Notice that the request has a type name `object` in the URI, which has been inferred from the `object` generic type parameter.